# Data-attributes are not rendered properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the fiddle I'm working with:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Z8wY/9/

The HTML part is:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="right">
       <div id="cityList" class="inner-table"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="left">
       <div id="cityList2" class="inner-table"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="middle">
       <div id="cityList3" class="inner-table"></div>
   </div>
```

The problem is when mycars[i] is having data-attribute ,the rendering is not happening.
Here is the fiddle when data- attributes are removed:http://jsfiddle.net/7Z8wY/10/

Can someone tell me a solution for rendering in case we have data-attributes(or how it can be done in other way)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string literals has syntax errors

```
mycars[0] = '<span data-modelName="city1">S</span>';
mycars[1] = '<span data-modelname="city2">SE</span>';
mycars[2] = '<span data-modelname="city3">SECUNDERABAD</span>';
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6c3dM/)

Since you have started the string with `"`, any occurrence of `"` within the string has to be escaped